# Efficiently transferring data from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The one above is the connection with SQL dedicated server, and the below is Oracle.

I need to get data from SQL server and get it into Oracle.

What are the best way  to make this?

Most table from SQL has more than 3 million rows, so copy to Oracle was way to slow.

Anyone got this issue before?

Somehow, I want to get this data from SQL with some method **fast**.

Comment: You can use [SSIS packages](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2011/export-sql-server-data-to-oracle-using-ssis/) to  move data from one source to other?

Answer (score 0):

I have had very slow performance (using SSIS) unless I use Oracles drivers (not Microsoft). Use an OLE DB destination with fast load and make sure that (if its OK) to use Table Lock on the OLE DB destination target.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider SQL Developer Migration ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/omwb-getstarted-093461.html ), which maybe is one way to address the problem

Comment: Let's say i use this Migration, once i have my data migrated to oracle, would I lose my source DB on SQL SERVER?